# Plotting Sentinel-5P data in xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4, satellite

I'm trying to plot a grid of air pollution data from a netCDF files in python using xarray. However, I'm facing a couple roadblocks.

To start off, here is the data that can be used to reproduce my code:
[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l0xfKYAOqxWf_knhmAn2d6Pyha4qpbJ0/view?usp=sharing)

When you try to import this data using xarray.open_dataset, you end up with a file that has zero coordinates or variables, and lots of attributes:

```
FILE_NAME = "test2.nc". ##I changed the name to make it shorter
xr.open_dataset(FILE_NAME)
```

So I created variables of the data and tried to import those into xarray:

```
prd='PRODUCT'        

metdata = "METADATA"

lat= ds.groups[prd].variables['latitude']
lon= ds.groups[prd].variables['longitude']
no2 = ds.groups[prd].variables['nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column']
scanline = ds.groups[prd].variables['scanline']
time = ds.groups[prd].variables['time']
ground_pixel = ds.groups[prd].variables['ground_pixel']

ds = xr.DataArray(no2,
                   dims=["time","x","y"],
                   coords={
                       "lon":(["time","x", "y"], lon)
                   }
#                    coords=[("time", time), ("x", scanline),("y", ground_pixel)]
)
```

As you can see above, I tried multiple ways of creating the coordinates, but I'm still getting an error. The data in this netCDF file is on an irregular grid, and I just want to be able to plot that accurately and quickly using xarray.

Does someone know how I can do this?

Comment: The data you have linked to requires a username/passport. However, this is data produced by NASA, so I would be very surprised if longitude/latitude/time are variables when they should be coordinates. It is likely that you cannot set them to coordinates. But see if you can add a non-password link to the data

Comment: Hi - link has been updated and should direct you to a Google Drive link.

Comment: I think you are meant to process the Sentinel data from level-2 to level-3 using a specific tool `harpconvert`. You could also another source of the data where it is already converted to L3, such as Google Earth Engine.